# Encrypted mp3 streaming to Flash SWF

Tags: asp.net, actionscript-3, flash, encryption

I have an asp.net web site that serves sample MP3 files to client Flash Players (SWF).

These files are downloadable by tons of download tools.

Although only registered members can access the high quality mp3 samples, my client wants to prevent these low quality MP3 files to be downloaded by download tools.

So I thought about this solution:

1. Convert these MP3 files to bytearrays on server side (ASP.NET)
2. Do some bitwise XOR operations (Simple encryption)
3. Write this array to aspx' responsestream
4. Modify Flash (.fla) to request to this new file/page/aspx
5. Do some bitwise XOR operations on Flash and convert it to the original MP3 as byte array. (Simple decryption)
6. Play the MP3

I was able to succeed till step 6. I cannot convert this byte array to a Sound object that Flash can play. I did a bit by bit comparison of the resulting array on the flash and the source array on ASP.NET. They are **equal**.

I'm open to completely different approaches. But I cannot use Flash Media Server. I need to be using Flash as3 and ASP.NET.

**Also very important!** The .mp3 must be downloaded/decrypted and played asynchronously (which I coud not succeed in doing)

Comment: There is a budget constraint (ZERO as usual).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@walkietokyo, thanks a lot for pointing me to the right direction. I succeeded in doing what I wanted. The keyword here was the `loadCompressedDataFromByteArray` function.

After tens of trial and errors I found out that `loadCompressedDataFromByteArray` was working in a differential manner.

It **appends** anything that it converts **to the end of the sound object** data.

Another issue: sound object doesn't continue playing the parts appended by `loadCompressedDataFromByteArray` after its `play` function is called.

So I implemented a sort of double buffering. Where I use 2 sound objects interchangeably.

My final (test) version is listed below. With the encryption (obfuscation) method I used (a simple XOR) no download manager or grabber or sniffer that I tested was able to play the Mp3s.

Flash (Client) side:

```
import flash.events.DataEvent;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.EventDispatcher;
import flash.events.OutputProgressEvent;
import flash.events.ProgressEvent;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.net.URLStream;
import flash.utils.ByteArray;
import flashx.textLayout.formats.Float;

var buffer:ByteArray;
var stream:URLStream;
var bufferReadPosition:uint = 0;
var bufferWritePosition:uint = 0;

var url:String = "http://www.blablabla.com/MusicServer.aspx?" + (new Date());

buffer = new ByteArray();
stream = new URLStream();
stream.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, onProgress);
stream.load(new URLRequest(url));

var s1:Sound = new Sound();
var s2:Sound = new Sound();

var channel1:SoundChannel;
var channel2:SoundChannel;

var pausePosition:int = 0;

var aSoundIsPlaying:Boolean = false;

var lastLoadedS1:Boolean = false;

var lastS1Length:int = 0;
var lastS2Length:int = 0;

function onProgress(e:ProgressEvent):void {
    var tmpData:ByteArray = new ByteArray();

    stream.readBytes(tmpData, 0, stream.bytesAvailable);

    var decryptedData:ByteArray = decryptData(tmpData); // Decrypt loaded data

    buffer.position = bufferWritePosition;
    buffer.writeBytes(decryptedData, 0, decryptedData.length); // Add decrypted data to buffer
    bufferWritePosition += decryptedData.length;

    if(lastLoadedS1)
    {
        buffer.position = lastS2Length;
        s2.loadCompressedDataFromByteArray(buffer, buffer.length - lastS2Length);
        lastS2Length = buffer.length;
    }
    else
    {
        buffer.position = lastS1Length;
        s1.loadCompressedDataFromByteArray(buffer, buffer.length - lastS1Length);
        lastS1Length = buffer.length;
    }

    if(!aSoundIsPlaying)
    {
        DecidePlay();
    }
}

function channel1Completed(e:Event):void
{
    DecidePlay();
}

function channel2Completed(e:Event):void
{
    DecidePlay();
}

function DecidePlay():void
{
    aSoundIsPlaying = false;

    if(lastLoadedS1)
    {
        channel1.stop();

        if(s2.length - s1.length > 10000)
        {
            //At least a 10 second buffer
            channel2 = s2.play(s1.length);
            channel2.addEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, channel2Completed);
            lastLoadedS1 = false;
            aSoundIsPlaying = true;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if(channel2 != null)
        {
            channel2.stop();
        }

        if(s1.length - s2.length > 10000)
        {
            //At least a 10 second buffer
            channel1 = s1.play(s2.length);
            channel1.addEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, channel1Completed);
            lastLoadedS1 = true;
            aSoundIsPlaying = true;
        }
    }
}

function decryptData(data:ByteArray):ByteArray {
    for(var i:int = 0;i<data.length;i++)
    {
        //Here put in your bitwise decryption code
    }
    return data;
}
```

ASP.NET server side (MusicServer.aspx):

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CopyStream(Mp3ToStream(Server.MapPath("blabla.mp3")), Response.OutputStream);

        this.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "blabla.mp3");
        this.Response.ContentType = "audio/mpeg";
        this.Response.End();
    }

    public static void CopyStream(Stream input, Stream output)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[32768];
        int read;
        while ((read = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < read; i++)
            {
                //Here put in your bitwise encryption code
            }

            output.Write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
    }

    public Stream Mp3ToStream(string filePath)
    {
        using (FileStream fileStream = File.OpenRead(filePath))
        {
            MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
            memStream.SetLength(fileStream.Length);
            fileStream.Read(memStream.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)fileStream.Length);
            return memStream;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I know this post is too old, but I need something like this. Could you please share me a demo project of this ?

Answer (score 3):

I agree with Peter Elliot that authentication probably is the easiest way to restrict access to the files. However, if you still need to explore the route of encrypting the files, I thought I'd expand a bit on Alex Vlad's answer.

What you need to do in order to be able to stream the audio file, decrypt it on the fly, and play it asynchronously is to use the `URLStream` class ([docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLStream.html)) in conjunction with the `Sound` class ([docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Sound.html)) and keeping a buffer of the partially downloaded content.

Some pseudocode to illustrate:

```
class AsyncEncryptedSoundPlayer extends Sound {
    var buffer:ByteArray;
    var stream:URLStream;
    var currSoundPosition:uint = 0;

    public function AsyncEncryptedSoundPlayer(url:String) {
        buffer = new ByteArray();
        stream = new URLStream();
        stream.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, onProgress);
        stream.load(new URLRequest(url));

        addEventListener(SampleDataEvent.SAMPLE_DATA, onSampleDataRequested);
    }

    function onProgress(e:ProgressEvent):void {
        var tmpData:ByteArray;
        stream.readBytes(tmpData, buffer.length, stream.bytesAvailable - buffer.length);
        var decryptedData:ByteArray = decryptData(tmpData); // Decrypt loaded data
        buffer.writeBytes(decryptedData, buffer.length, decryptedData.length); // Add decrypted data to buffer
    }

    function onSampleDataRequested(e:ProgressEvent):void {
        // Feed samples from the buffer to the Sound instance
        // You may have to pause the audio to increase the buffer it the download speed isn't high enough
        event.data.writeBytes(buffer, currSoundPosition, 2048);
        currSoundPosition += 2048;
    }

    function decryptedData(data:ByteArray):void {
        // Returns decrypted data
    }
}
```

This is obviously a very rough outline of a class, but I hope it will point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks walkietokyo. This was one of my first trials. "Using pure URLRequests" instead of using Sound.Load's mechanism. But I got stuck at converting these downloaded partial streams to playable partial (in memory) MP3s. Do you think that it is possible to combine @fsbmain's solution with yours?

Comment: @erich007 Ah, yeah. Since it's a compressed audio file, you'd have to decode the MP3 as well. Have you tried using the `Sound.loadCompressedDataFromByteArray` method? ([link](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Sound.html#loadCompressedDataFromByteArray()))

Answer (score 1):

what might be simpler than encrypting the data coming back from your service is instead authenticating requests so that only your swf can request the files.

You can accomplish this in the same way that say, the Amazon APIs work: build a request that includes a number of parameters, including a timestamp.  hash all of these arguments together in an HMAC (HMAC-SHA256 is available in the [as3crypto library](http://code.google.com/p/as3crypto/)) along with a private key embedded in your swf.  Your server end authenticates this request, ensuring that the hash is valid and that it is close enough to the timestamp.  Any requests with a bad hash, or using a request with a timestamp too far in the past (replay attack) are denied.

This is certainly not perfect security.  Any sufficiently motivated user could disassemble your swf and pull out your auth key, or grab the mp3 from their browser cache.  But then again, any mechanism you are going to use will have those issues.  This removes the overhead of having to encrypt and decrypt all of your files, instead moving the work over to the request generation phase.

Comment: But Peter, I don't see how this solves my issue. Think of youtube downloader tools... While you watch the video a download button appears next to the video as the tool grabs the raw data. So even if I authenticate the flash player the server will send a clean mp3 as a response. So the tool will be able to grab it again...

Comment: the idea is authenticating the requests prevents outside tools from being able to make requests for the data from your server.  Doesn't stop users from grabbing it out of their browser cache, but then again your XOR solution doesn't really stop that either.

Answer (score 0):

Flash `Sound` supports only streaming mp3 playing that is you can play only mp3 by direct link. But you can send swf file with embeded mp3 withing it and this swf can be encrypted in the same way as you encrypt mp3.

as3 code for embedding and using mp3:

```
public class Sounds
{
    [Embed(source="/../assets/sounds/sound1.mp3")]
    private static const sound1:Class;
}
```

after loading this swf by the `Loader` you can access to the sound in this way:

```
var domain:ApplicationDomain = ApplicationDomain.currentDomain; // <-- ApplicationDomain where you load sounds.swf
var soundClass:Class = domain.getDefinition("Sounds_sound1");
var sound:Sound = new soundClass();
sound.play();
```

Be sure, that you do at least one of the follows:

- give different names for sound class (`sound1`)
- give different name for holder class (`Sounds`)
- or load sound.swf into different application domains

to prevent class names overlapping.

Unfortunate this approach doesn't allow you to streaming play sound, you have to load whole swf, decrypt it and only after that you will be able to play sound.

Comment: As you also mention, it is not asynchronous. I already came across with this solution... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

please have a look here:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/SampleDataEvent.html

and here:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WSE523B839-C626-4983-B9C0-07CF1A087ED7.html

Comment: Checked, digested and tested these for the last 2 days. These links do not help me download and play the song "asynchronously".